# How to maintain a table of all proxy models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-inheritance

I have a model `A` and want to make subclasses of it.

```py
class A(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    data = models.JSONField()
    
    def compute():
            pass

class B(A):
    def compute():
        df = self.go_get_data()
        self.data = self.process(df)

class C(A):
    def compute():
        df = self.go_get_other_data()
        self.data = self.process_another_way(df)

# ... other subclasses of A
```

`B` and `C` should not have their own tables, so I decided to use the `proxy` attirbute of `Meta`. However, I want there to be a table of all the implemented proxies.
In particular, I want to keep a record of the name and description of each subclass.
For example, for `B`, the name would be `"B"` and the description would be the docstring for `B`.
So I made another model:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    # The name of the class
    name = models.String()
    # The docstring of the class
    desc = models.String()
    # A unique identifier, different from the Django ID,
    # that allows for smoothly changing the name of the class
    identifier = models.Int()
```

Now, I want it so when I create an `A`, I can only choose between the different subclasses of `A`.
Hence the `Type` table should always be up-to-date.
For example, if I want to unit-test the behavior of `B`, I'll need to use the corresponding `Type` instance to create an instance of `B`, so **that `Type` instance already needs to be in the database**.

Looking over on the [Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data), I see two ways to achieve this: fixtures and data migrations.
Fixtures aren't dynamic enough for my usecase, since the attributes literally come from the code. That leaves me with data migrations.

I tried writing one, that goes something like this:

```py
def update_results(apps, schema_editor):
    A = apps.get_model("app", "A")
    Type = apps.get_model("app", "Type")
    subclasses = get_all_subclasses(A)
    for cls in subclasses:
        id = cls.get_identifier()
        Type.objects.update_or_create(
            identifier=id,
            defaults=dict(name=cls.__name__, desc=cls.__desc__)
        )
    
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        RunPython(update_results)
    ]
    
    # ... other stuff
```

The problem is, I don't see how to store the identifier within the class, so that the Django `Model` instance can recover it.
So far, here is what I have tried:

I have tried using the fairly new `__init_subclass__` construct of Python. So my code now looks like:

```py
class A:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, identifier=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if identifier is None:
            raise ValueError()
        cls.identifier = identifier
        Type.objects.update_or_create(
            identifier=identifier,
            defaults=dict(name=cls.__name__, desc=cls.__doc__)
        )
    
    # ... the rest of A

# The identifier should never change, so that even if the
# name of the class changes, we still know which subclass is referred to
class B(A, identifier=3):

    # ... the rest of B
```

But this `update_or_create` fails when the database is new (e.g. during unit tests), because the `Type` table does not exist.
When I have this problem in development (we're still in early stages so deleting the DB is still sensible), I have to go
comment out the `update_or_create` in `__init_subclass__`. I can then migrate and put it back in.

Of course, this solution is also not great because `__init_subclass__` is run way more than necessary. Ideally this machinery would only happen at migration.

So there you have it! I hope the problem statement makes sense.

Thanks for reading this far and I look forward to hearing from you; even if you have other things to do, I wish you a good rest of your day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from Django-expert friends, I solved this with the [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal.
I removed the `update_or_create` in `__init_subclass`, and in `project/app/apps.py` I added:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate


def get_all_subclasses(cls):
    """Get all subclasses of a class, recursively.

    Used to get a list of all the implemented As.
    """
    all_subclasses = []

    for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
        all_subclasses.append(subclass)
        all_subclasses.extend(get_all_subclasses(subclass))

    return all_subclasses


def update_As(sender=None, **kwargs):
    """Get a list of all implemented As and write them in the database.

    More precisely, each model is used to instantiate a Type, which will be used to identify As.
    """
    from app.models import A, Type

    subclasses = get_all_subclasses(A)
    for cls in subclasses:
        id = cls.identifier
        Type.objects.update_or_create(identifier=id, defaults=dict(name=cls.__name__, desc=cls.__doc__))


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "app"

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(update_As, sender=self)
```

Hope this is helpful for future Django coders in need!